# TextView not showing up in other activity

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

I have been able to pass data to other activities except this one. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong. The only error i'm getting is that my TextView showmsg is NOT showing up in the new activity. Does anyone know why?

```
 public class MyScanActivity extends Activity
{


private static final String MY_CARDIO_APP_TOKEN = "NOT THE PROBLEM";

final String TAG = getClass().getName();

private Button scanButton;
private TextView resultTextView;
private Button buttonBack;

private TextView showmsg;



private int MY_SCAN_REQUEST_CODE = 100; // arbitrary int

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myscan);

    Intent in = getIntent();
    if (in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr") != null) {
        final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
        setmsg.setText(in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr"));             
    }

    resultTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);
    scanButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.scanButton);
    buttonBack = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBack);
    showmsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
```

Comment: What are you displaying in showmsg?

Comment: Are you setting setmsg to R.id.showmsg on purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not too many options for how your text can be not shown.

1. You have the view itself messed up:  Check this by putting some sample text in the XML file using `android:text="TEST"` in the TextView showmsg.  Your text should appear, unless your text is the wrong color or size, or something else happens to be above it.
2. You aren't actually finding it with `findViewById()`  (I hope you've double checked that in a debugger) I agree with alex that you might not want `R.id.showmsg`.  Did you mean to put `R.id.resultTextView` there instead?
3. Your passed text is not actually coming through.  You should do a log statement, like `Log.v(TAG, "Passed text is " + in.getCharSequenceExtra("urs"));` and make sure the text is actually coming through.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't test it. but i think that is the reason.

change here:

```
if (in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr") != null) {
    final TextView setmsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
    setmsg.setText(in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr"));             
}
```

with this:

```
showmsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showmsg);
if (in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr") != null) {
    showmsg.setText(in.getCharSequenceExtra("usr"));             
}
```